# Von Neumann hierarchy and finite transitive closures

Tags: set-theory

Let $V_\alpha$ be the elements of the Von Neumann hierarchy and, given a set $S$, define its transitive closure, $tc(S)$, as the smallest transitive set such that $S \subseteq tc(S)$.
I'm not very familiar with this concepts so maybe my question will be trivial, but how do I show that $S \in V_\omega \iff |tc(S)| \lt \aleph_0$? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: This can be proved in several ways depending on what you've seen so far. Where did this exercise come from? A book? Course? Have you seen any theorems/lemmas/propositions about transitive sets, about the von Neumann hierarchy, about transitive closures?

Comment: Please add more context.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've not seen so much, just enough to introduce the well-foundation axiom (not sure if it's translated that way). This was left as an exercise at the end of the professor's notes. Also there is an hint and it says try to prove it by induction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction is fairly immediate:

If $S\in V_\omega$, then $S\subseteq V_n$ for some $n<\omega$, so $\operatorname{tc}(S)\subseteq V_n$ as well, since $V_n$ is a transitive set (why?). But since $V_n$ is also finite (why?), that means that $\operatorname{tc}(S)$ must be finite.

In the other direction, there are multiple approaches you can take. But here's a fairly straightforward one:

> **Lemma**. If $X$ is a transitive set of von Neumann rank $\alpha$ (i.e., $X\in V_{\alpha+1}\setminus V_\alpha$), then the function $\rho$ mapping the elements of $X$ to their von Neumann rank is surjective onto $\alpha$.

*Proof*. We prove this by induction on $\alpha$. Let $X$ be such a transitive set of rank $\alpha$. Let $\beta<\alpha$ and let $x\in X$ be a set of von Neumann rank $\beta$, then $\operatorname{tc}(x)\subseteq X\cap V_\beta$. By the induction hypothesis on $\beta$, $\rho\restriction\operatorname{tc}(x)$ is surjective onto $\beta$.

Now, note that for any $\beta<\alpha$ there is some $x\in X$ of von Neumann rank at least $\beta$, so the image of $\rho$ must cover at least $\beta$, for any $\beta<\alpha$. And therefore the image must cover $\alpha$ itself. $\square$

> **Corollary.** If $X\notin V_\omega$, then its transitive closure is infinite.

*Proof.* If $X\notin V_\omega$, then it has an infinite von Neumann rank, so by the above, its transitive closure must map onto some infinite ordinal, and therefore must be infinite. $\square$